# d3 csv returns object without rows just functions

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am trying to load titanic data into d3. I am writing the following in the chrome console:

```
    d3.csv("titanic_data.csv");
```

The data and html file are in the same folder and the server i set up is in that folder too. The function returns this:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llfZq.png)

How do I get the csv function to return the actual data?

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options:

(1) provide a callback:

```
d3.csv("titanic_data.csv", function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("something went wrong", error);
    } else {
        console.log("data: ", data);
    }
})
```

or

(2) invoke get:

```
d3.csv("titanic_data.csv")
  .get(function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("something went wrong", error);
    } else {
        console.log("data: ", data);
    }
})
```

Why this way? From [d3.csv](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/CSV#csv) documentation:

> d3.**csv**(url[[, accessor], callback])
>
> Issues an HTTP GET (...) The request is processed asynchronously, such that this method returns immediately after opening the request. When the CSV data is available, the specified callback will be invoked with the parsed rows as the argument.